# jbpm 5 build failed as protocol downgrade to http from https

Tags: installation, jbpm

jbpm 5 build failed (ant install.demo) for Jbpm designer as redirection detected from https to http protocol.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMqRw.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me - 
as the error log describes, ant build not able to download jbpm designer because of the protocol downgrade, so either change security setting or download that file explicitly from the mentioned url and place it in jbpm-5.4.0.Final-installer\jbpm-installer\lib

https://sourceforge.net/projects/jbpm/files/designer/designer-2.4/jbpm-designer-2.4.0.Final-jboss7.war/

Cheers,
Keep calm and coding on.